# Why does this character get affected in Infinity War?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In the aftermath of Thanos snapping his fingers, we see that

> Drax is also among the people to disappear.

Previously in the movie, this character mentioned that Thanos had already been to their planet and killed half the population. Why would they be included in Thanos' plan again?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187369/what-happened-to-the-planets-thanos-already-culled

Comment: Related :[Does Thanos intend to exert his plan on each planet individually or the entire universe as a whole?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88821/does-thanos-intend-to-exert-his-plan-on-each-planet-individually-or-the-entire-u)

Answer (score 3):

As per [the question Ankit Sharma linked](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88821/does-thanos-intend-to-exert-his-plan-on-each-planet-individually-or-the-entire-u?rq=1), it appears that Thanos' culling is being applied planet-by-planet, not civilisation-by-civilisation. We don't know whether Drax's planet was affected a second time, but it doesn't matter because *Drax was not on his planet at the time*. He was on Titan. So his planet may have been spared from the event, but Drax wasn't.

Comment: Most people were wiped out on Titan, weren't they?  I think only Iron Man survived from that group

Comment: @m1gp0z Nebula survived as well, and I'm sure there was a third person.

Answer (score 0):

Thanos *had* killed half of the people on his planet, but that was a while ago. By that time, his planet probably recovered and maybe even grown a little, so he could be part of the group killed to get his planet back to normal.

Comment: If that's the case, then Thanos would know that his 50%-genocide plan would have to be repeated every few generations. I'm not saying he didn't know that, but don't remember him mentioning anything about that in the movie. The opposite seemed to be true:  he acted as though wiping out 50% of sentient beings one time would reset everything and establish balance and everyone would have plenty to eat.

Comment: It couldn't be more than 100 years ago from happening that incident. Usually it's not possible to re-populate that much within that amount of time

Comment: @Vishwa ... you say that but our population doubling time peaked at 35 years in the 1960s.

Comment: @iandotkelly in earth. not half assassinated. without destroying half the world. without kids without parents and other refugees to take care about. with no huge disaster and stuff...